# How to create a package that is most likely not to cause versioning problems?

Tags: nuget

I created a NuGet package with an empty logger and my package depends on **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions**.

My `PackageReference` line *and* my `dependency` in the `.nuspec` file are set to **1.0.0** with no special syntax which I understand means `>=`.

My empty logger works just fine with this version and I thought using the lowest working version of the abstractions lib would make my package easier to consume by applications which are likely to have greater versions.

However, when I've referenced my package from an xUnit test project I have a red compiler error CS1705.

My test project references two packages:

1. The project its testing, which is an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages site that in turn references the same logging abstractions package which is included in **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0** metapackage.
2. My empty logger package, which, in turn references the logging abstractions 1.0.0.0 as I have described.

Compiler error from the test proj says:

> Assembly (Razor Pages proj) uses (Abstractions 2.2.0.0) which has a higher version than referenced assembly (Abstractions) with identity (Abstractions 1.0.0.0).

My package can use the higher version so what am I missing?

---

**Edit**

Here's a high fidelity diagram ;)

[image: Dependency graph]

- T is "xUnit Proj".
- W is the "Website Proj" under test.
- E is the empty logger package (Evoq.Instrumentation on nuget.org)
- A is metapackage Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0
- L is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

There's the nearest wins rule, which I think means that the dependency from T to L via E would win and version 2.0.0 would be used but I'd expect a package downgrade warning not a hard compiler error.

Nearest wins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins

**Edit 2**

It just occured to me that T > W is a project reference. So maybe that's short-circuiting the NuGet resolution. I'll add a ref from T to A directly and see if that solves it.

Comment: I ran `dotnet new mvc`, `dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions --version 1.0.0`, `dotnet build` and didn't get any error. Can you provide more detailed repro instructions, or a sample that I can download?

Comment: @zivkan Big thanks for taking the time to do that. I've added a diagram to the question. I'm exploring the nearest-wins idea this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot T > W is a project reference. So I think that was short-circuiting the NuGet resolution I was expecting to take place.

I added a ref from T to A directly and that solved it.

Comment: I believe project to project references participate in the "nearest wins" algorithm the same way that a package reference does, so I don't think the fact it's a project reference really matters. nearest wins just isn't intuitive to many people, including myself. But one of the reasons it exists is so you can make a package a direct dependency to override whatever version transitive dependencies request.

Comment: and like you said in your edit to the question, I also would expect a package downgrade warning, rather than a compiler error. But since you resolved it with a direct package reference, I'm not going to investigate it.